# How to select specific and distincet number of records in multiple columns?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have such table in MySql database.

```
                    "table1"
____________________________________________________
id      Category      Type     rating     Value
----------------------------------------------------
1          1           1         5          23
2          1           1         6          27
3          2           1         4          26
4          2           2         2          25
5          3           1         4          21
6          3           1         5          28
```

I wand to select specific number of distinct document that have unique category and type in this table. like this:

```
select distinct category, type from table1 order by rating desc limit 0,3
```

```
        "table2"
__________________________
id      Category      Type     
--------------------------
1          1           1       
5          3           1    
3          2           1
```

and then select all value from table where have this categories and types.

```
select id,value from table1 where type and category is in table2
```

```
                    "table3"
____________________________________________________
id      Category      Type     rating     Value
----------------------------------------------------
1          1           1         5          23
2          1           1         6          27
5          3           1         4          21
6          3           1         5          28
3          2           1         4          26
```

how i can use one Sql statement for this goal?

thx.

Comment: How can a `LIMIT 0,2` query return 3 rows?

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos excuse me i dont test it, i think this retuned 3 row.

Comment: Actually it returns only 2 rows. If you want the top 3 `rating` rows for unique `Category, Type` values then you can use the query posted in my answer.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos Ok. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using your query to produce a derived table. Then join this derived table with the original one:

```
SELECT id, t1.Category, t1.Type, rating, Value
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT category, type 
            FROM table1 
            ORDER BY rating DESC limit 0,2) AS t2
ON t1.category = t2.category AND t1.type = t2.type
```

But the above does not actually return the expected result set of the OP. In case you want all rows having `(Category, Type)` values related to the top 3 rating values, then you can use:

```
SELECT id, t1.Category, t1.Type, rating, Value
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT category, type
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY category, type
  ORDER BY MAX(rating) DESC LIMIT 0,3
) AS t2 ON t1.category = t2.category AND t1.type = t2.type
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4518/8)